# Problem with button for menu, toggle function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have a problem with the button for a menu on smaller screen size devices (under 700px width). The toggle function doesn't work. I don't know what is wrong. I have set a button to show in screen size less than 700px, hide my social menu, and gave a real menu proper width. Also, I have set CSS for a class of "show", but I don't know how to sign it on "main-nav ul". I hope you get me. Here is my HTML, CSS and, JS code:

HTML with JS script on the end

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Responsive Navigation Menu Bar</title>    
    </head>

    <body>
        <section class="top-bar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="top-bar-content">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="img/Logo.png" alt="Gravitarium logo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="info flex">
                        <div class="info-content flex">
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="infos">
                                <a href="tel:+180045678923"><p>Have Any Questions?</p></a>
                                <p>+1-800-456-789-23</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info-content flex">
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="infos">
                                <p>Visit Us Daily</p>
                                <p>My Street 69, Novi Sad</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info-content flex">
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="fas fa-hourglass-half"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="infos">
                                <p>Our Working Hours</p>
                                <p>Mon-Fri: 8.00 - 18.00</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </section>

        <navigation class="menu">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="menu-btn">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                </div>               
                <div class="nav flex">
                    <div class="main-nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social-nav">
                        <ul >
                            <li><a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://pinterest.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://github.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </navigation>
        <script>
            document.querySelector('.menu-btn').addEventListener('click', () => document.querySelector('.main-nav ul').classList.toggle('.show'));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

=====CSS=====

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap');

:root {
    --pc: #f7941d; /*Primary Color*/
    --sc: #cfcfcf; /*Secondary Color*/
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    background: var(--sc);
}

a, ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.top-bar {
    background: #333;
    padding: 20px 0 40px 0;
}

.top-bar-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    align-items: center;
}

.top-bar-content .logo {
    width: 35%;
}

.top-bar-content .info i {
    color: var(--pc);
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.top-bar-content .infos p:first-child {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: var(--sc) !important;
    font-weight: 200;
} 

.top-bar-content .infos p:last-child {
    color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .top-bar-content .info-content {
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .top-bar-content .info i {
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .top-bar-content .infos p:first-child  {
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {    
    .top-bar-content .info i {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .top-bar-content .infos p  {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {    
    .top-bar-content .info i {
        display: none;
    }
    .top-bar-content .info {
        flex-direction: column;        
    }
    .top-bar-content .infos  {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        border-bottom: 1px dashed var(--sc);
    }
    .top-bar-content .logo {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* Navigation Style */
.menu .container {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px;    
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.menu .nav {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}

.menu .main-nav ul,
.menu .social-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;    
}

.menu .social-nav ul {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.menu .main-nav ul li:nth-child(n+1) {
    margin-right: 30px;    
}

.menu .main-nav ul li a {
    font-weight: 500;
}

.menu .main-nav ul li a:hover {
    color:  var(--pc);
    transition: .3s;
    border-bottom: 5px solid var(--pc);
}

.menu .social-nav ul li:nth-last-child(n+2) {
    margin-right: 30px;    
}

.menu .social-nav ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.menu .social-nav ul li a:hover {
    color: var(--pc);
    transition: .3s;     
}

.menu .social-nav ul li:hover {
    transform: rotate(720deg);
    transition: 1s; 
}

.menu-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 968px) {
    .social-nav {
        display: none;
    }
    .menu .nav {        
        grid-template-columns: auto;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .menu-btn {
        display: block;
        top: 195px;
    }
    .menu-btn:hover {
        color: var(--pc);
        transition: .3s;
    }    
    .menu .main-nav ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: #f2f2f2;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
        opacity: 0.9;
        padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
        transform: translateX(-500px);
    }
    .menu .main-nav ul.show {
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    .menu .main-nav ul li {
        padding: 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .menu .main-nav ul li:last-child {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I change your script a little, it seems to work:

```
document.querySelector('.menu-btn').addEventListener('click', () => document.querySelector('.menu .main-nav ul').classList.toggle('show'));
```

Main problem might have been that you tried to toggle '.show' instead of 'show' (without the dot)?

Also the first querySelector was for the 'click' event (.menu-btn) and the second querySelector for the menu (.menu .main-nav ul).

Comment: Good to hear! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use bootstrap for this?
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/
under a certain width it will automatically collapse and you will be able to click on it to toggle it

Comment: I want to build this without Bootstrap. Collapsing is good, but toggle doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You *querySelector* this: `('.main-nav ul')`
Maybe it should be: `('.menu .main-nav ul')`